# Attach Eclipse to a remote process

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, intellij-idea

In Intellij Idea it is possible to make it listen to a remote process doing the following :

Run -> Edit configurations -> Add new configuration -> Remote.

I was wondering if it is possible to do the same in Eclipse IDE ...

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to attach remote debugging process here is [process](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-to-setup-remote-debugging-in.html) . You question is not sure on which case you want this in your application, but you may try this as starting point (if not for debugging purpose).